# Events Getting merged in OPENNMS

Tags: snmp, opennms

I am sending multiple trap to opennms as an event. But those events are getting merged on Opennms portal and In database the latest event is getting displayed. Is this is a bug or functionality. And how can we segregate the traps on portal end (opennms end).

Answer (score 0):

An event definition can have a reduction key. This key is used to de-duplicate recurring events, especially for SNMP traps. To give you help the event definition would be useful.